# massive delays in alerts reception, is the problem in SP or Exchange?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, exchange-server

on a pool of 50 people some people receive the alert after 8 minutes, others after one hour. It wasn't like that some months ago, but the timing gets worse.

The alerts are set on an announcement list that has an average of 2 announcements per week.

The alerts have been set MANUALLY for everybody.

Is the problem in SP and where do I have to look? is it in Exchange?

SP on premise 2013, exchange server 2010 on premise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer, at least for my case.

SharePoint is partially responsible, since the timer job for the Immediate alerts are set to run every 5 minutes. It is possible to run it every 1 but this will put a weight on the server. I left it at 5 minutes which was the average time when it used to work properly.

I came to know that in my workplace they added an extra layer of security in the firewall/antispam that is unfortunately holding up the sharepoint alerts causing this disruption on several people. There is a queue and some alerts are faster than others but still slower than the normal 5 minutes.